# Suddenly my display turns grey!

Tags: display

When I'm working suddenly the mouse doesn't respond and the display turns gray or black. Although I can press any key ( I can't see what I'm doing ) nothing happens at all!!. The only way to recover my PC is to turn it off.

It has happened twice now and I've lost lots of work. This has started right after I upgraded drivers for my video hardware ATI.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to purge the drivers to default state

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

Then reboot and see if the problem remains. Than you can try reinstall the drivers using terminal https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Comment: I'll try! Thx a lot